# Oracle Apex Checksum error on custom link

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a link inside a PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region with the following  tag:

```
<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:209:&SESSION.:::209:P209_MY_REPORT,P209_GROUPS,P209_TYPES,P209_INDUSTRIES:MyReportName,Group1:Group2:Group3',Type1:Type2:Type3:Type4,Finance:Communications:Sports:">
```

All page 209 target being checkbox group items (except for the first one (P209_MY_REPORT).
But then I'm getting this error:

"no checksum was provided to show processing for a page that requires a checksum when one or more request, clear cache, or argument values are passed as parameters."

Anybody knows why?

Thanks

Comment: As the message states, the page is configured to require a checksum as part of the URL when passing argument values.

Comment: thanks, was finally able to figure out how to add the checksum:
https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-do-i-generate-a-page-checksum-using-apex-util-prepare-u-9815

Comment: Please set page level property Page Access Protection = "Unrestricted"
and also check the primary key item property remove the Session State Protection  ="Unrestricted" and save the page

Now refresh the page and run the page and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set page level property Page Access Protection = "Unrestricted"
[image]

and also check the primary key item property remove the Session State Protection  ="Unrestricted" and save the page

[image]

Now refresh the page and run the page and check it.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. It just lowers security down for pages/applications which is not good or recommended solution.